Missing privacy manifest for ionic capacitor project
I successfully submitted my app for review on the App Store, but I received a warning about missing privacy manifests for several SDKs included in my app. The message mentions that starting November 12, 2024, SDKs identified as privacy-impacting must include a privacy manifest file. Below are the SDKs listed in the warning:

Capacitor.framework

Cordova.framework

FBLPromises.framework

FirebaseCore.framework

FirebaseCoreInternal.framework

FirebaseInstallations.framework

FirebaseMessaging.framework

GTMSessionFetcher.framework

GoogleDataTransport.framework

GoogleToolboxForMac.framework


The message suggests contacting the SDK providers to obtain updated versions that include the required privacy manifest file. However, I'm unsure how to proceed with this or what specific steps I need to take to resolve this issue.
Questions:

How can I ensure that the SDKs I am using include the required privacy manifests?

What steps should I take to update these SDKs with the necessary privacy information?

Are there specific actions I need to take within Xcode or App Store Connect to handle this update?


For reference, here is the link provided in the warning: Apple's Third-Party SDK Requirements.
Any guidance on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.


Update all SDKs to the latest version. In the changelog you will find the information from which SDK version the privacy manifest is included.
Just update the SDKs to the latest version by updating the respective Capacitor plugin.
Usually not. If it does, it is described in the documentation of the SDK/Capacitor plugin.


Did you happen to fix your issue? I've updated all my SDKs but still get the warning due to GoogleToolboxForMac

To which version have you updated the plugins?

In my case it's @capacitor-mlkit/barcode-scanning, they're going to update it soon
